# ACF choices to register in WPML

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

As WPML does not provide a solution to translate `[choices]` fields I would like to add a custom function to register it within WPML, however I am not a star in php, but I have below but it doesn't register it in WPML String Translation:

```
$field = get_field_object( 'type_of_property' ); // acf field with choices
if (!empty($field['choices'])) {
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $choice ){
        do_action( 'wpml_register_single_string', 'ACF Domain', 'name'.$choice , $choice );
        $acflabel= apply_filters( 'wpml_translate_single_string', $choice, 'ACF Domain', 'name'.$choice, NULL );
        echo ' - ' . $acflabel;
    }
}
```

Is above method going into the right direction or do I need to call all the choices within the `type_of_property` field?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do this:

```
$field = get_field_object( 'type_of_property' );
if ( !empty( $field['choices'] ) ) {
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $choice ){
        echo ' - ' . __( $choice, 'ACF Domain' );
    }
}
```

Then scan your theme/plugin for strings:

1. In admin dashboard go to *WPML > Theme and Plugins Localization*
2. Select the theme or plugin and click to scan it.
3. After the scan is done, you should be able to find the strings on the String Translation page.

Doc:

[https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/finding-strings-that-dont-appear-on-the-string-translation-page/#:~:text=To%20scan%20for%20hard%2Dcoded%20strings%3A](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/finding-strings-that-dont-appear-on-the-string-translation-page/#:%7E:text=To%20scan%20for%20hard%2Dcoded%20strings%3A)

Comment: it looks promising, but it doesn't register anything. Sure it should not hook on `wpml_register_single_string`?

Comment: Do you have a multi-server setup? If yes check the bottom of this doc: https://wpml.org/faq/getting-string-translation-to-work/

Comment: No multi-server. I think it needs to have add_action function to be able to print it on a post.